# php link code - separate the code

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, hyperlink

hi i need help with a small bit of code for my wordpress theme.

```
  <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
  <?php
  global $post;
  foreach(get_the_tags($post->ID) as $tag) {
  echo ' <li>'.$tag->name.', </li>';
  }
  ?>
  </a>
```

the code

```
<?php echo $link; ?>
```

this is for a link of a website that is already on the page the link part works great the only issue is i want the links (tags that are being used as keywords/anchor text)to be seo friendly for outbound links

what changes are needed? feel free to spice the link up for seo :)

Comment: line 5 of the code you pasted looks goofy..Why do you have nested php tags and echo tags? am I missing something?

Comment: my bad :) was trying something didnt mean to post that code i have updated the code now - im noob to this so i am trying stuff to see if i can fix this issue hence why i came here as i am 100% stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting the same link for each of the tags, then this is a solution:

```
<ul>
  <?php
    global $post;
    foreach( get_the_tags($post->ID) as $tag ) {
      echo '<li><a href="' . $link . '?>" title="A title for the link">' . $tag->name . '</a></li>';
    }
  ?>
</ul>
```

Please note: I've added the unordered list start and end elements as these were missing, these could also be ordered list start and ends.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
to reflect your code changes.

The code still looks the same...I would assume it should look something like this: (and I could be completely wrong) :)

```
      <?php
  global $post;
  foreach(get_the_tags($post->ID) as $tag) {
  echo ' <li>'.$tag->name.'</li>';
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your time, please recheck my code i replied before updating

Comment: what do you get if you echo $tag->name ?

Comment: i get the wp tags unlinked which is what i was going for as these are now needed to be outbound links the link code is <?php echo $link; ?>.

Comment: sorry its not :) i mean i am now needing these tags to have a link to 
<?php echo $link; ?> i tried to wrap the whole thing but i get all tags in a line and a single link not each one... for example if the listing on my wp theme is this site the keywords would be example 1 and example 2 . with the code above it displays them but there both one link (not separated) i was trying to achieve both to be single links so the anchor text for them be different